# Livewire looks for classes in the root of project

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I'm creating a laravel package which requires Livewire uppon installation.

I have created most of the logic to implement the components and namespaces etc. to make this work.

But whenenver I try to render a component in a view I get the following error

```
Livewire\Exceptions\ComponentNotFoundException
Component [sidebar] class not found: [App\Http\Livewire\Sidebar]
```

It seems that it looks in the root of my project for the `app/HTTP/Livewire/Sidebar` class which is obviously not there because all of my livewire classes are in:

```
packages/mypackage/newpackage/src/app/HTTP/Livewire
```

This is how my view looks like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    @livewireStyles
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            @section('sidebar')
                @livewire('sidebar')
            @show
        </div>
        <div class="col-9"></div>
    </div>
</div>
 @yield('content')
 @livewireScripts
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my ServiceProvider:

```
 namespace MyPackage\NewPackage;
    use App\Http\Livewire\Sidebar;
    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
    use Livewire\Livewire;
    
    
    class WischAdminServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{
        public function boot(){
            
            $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'/routes/web.php');
            $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__.'/database/migrations');
            $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/resources/views', 'newpackage');
            
            Livewire::component('newpackage::sidebar',Sidebar::class);
        }
        
        public function register(){
            
        }
    }
```

and this is my Livewire component:

```
namespace  App\Http\Livewire;


use Livewire\Component;

class Sidebar extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        
        return view('livewire.sidebar');
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `namespace  App\Http\Livewire;` really the correct namespace for your component? `use App\Http\Livewire\Sidebar;` also looks like it points to the wrong component?

Comment: @brombeer It might be wrong but I don't understand how it should be.